# Hide "pull to refresh" view when scroll up the listview in Android

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

I've integrated pull to refresh ([chrisbanes](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh)) in my project. I have a problem that when I scroll up the list view, after the first item of the list view showed, the "pull to refresh" view showed in a short period of time (my finger has not touched the Android screen). I want that when the user performs a scroll action, the list view scrolls and stops at the first item, not showing the "pull to refresh" view.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Check OverScroll feature of scroll view.

Comment: Thank for your answer @Toris. I disable overscroll by android:overScrollMode="never"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the OverScroll feature of listview would solve my problem.

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```

Thank you!